# SVG stroke-dash rendering issue on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a path where I'm setting both `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` to it's total length by using `getTotalLength()` method in JS.

This will make the stroke appear invisible which is my intent.

I added a duplicate light-blue path underneath as visual aid what the path looks like.

The issue is that in Safari, there's a small remainder of the stroke at the right of the path.

In the demo I have 3 paths, that appear to be duplicates, but their "path" attributes are different. The first one has relative coordinates and has transform attribute ( accidentally left over from Inkscape Program ). The second one has absolute coordinates. The third one has relative coordinates.

Only the 1st path correctly hides it's stroke in Safari

```js
const pathA = document.querySelector(".path-A");
const pathB = document.querySelector(".path-B");
const pathC = document.querySelector(".path-C");

pathA.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", pathA.getTotalLength());
pathA.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", pathA.getTotalLength());

pathB.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", pathB.getTotalLength());
pathB.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", pathB.getTotalLength());

pathC.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", pathC.getTotalLength());
pathC.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", pathC.getTotalLength());
```

```css
svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <div>Path format set to Relative. <br/> Also has translate property accidently left over from Inkscape Program</div>
  <div>The only one that correctly hides in Safari</div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="278.7779" height="172.781" viewBox="0 0 73.76 45.715">
    <g fill="none" stroke="#00aad4" stroke-linecap="round">
      <path
        d="m 28.160858,82.187983 h 7.650572 l 2.617177,-10.690495 6.864897,25.620138 3.161464,-36.349135 3.960852,28.486407 1.112568,-6.93955 h 8.747067 l 1.276252,-7.39712 4.447672,23.966019 2.307643,-38.08671 1.613403,15.155399 h 7.50004 l 3.378248,16.804952 1.66252,-13.510699 h 15.694617"
        opacity=".165" stroke-width=".965" stroke-linejoin="round" transform="translate(-27.2784 -54.0512)" />
      <path class="path-A"
        d="m 28.160858,82.187983 h 7.650572 l 2.617177,-10.690495 6.864897,25.620139 3.161464,-36.349136 3.960852,28.486407 1.112568,-6.93955 h 8.747067 l 1.276252,-7.39712 4.447672,23.966019 2.307643,-38.08671 1.613403,15.155399 h 7.50004 l 3.378248,16.804952 1.66252,-13.510699 h 15.694617"
        stroke-width="1.765" stroke-linejoin="round" transform="translate(-27.2784 -54.0512)" />
    </g>
  </svg>
  <div>Path format set to Absolute</div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 73.76 45.715" height="172.781" width="278.7779">
    <g fill="none" stroke="#00aad4" stroke-linecap="round">
      <path
        d="M.8825 28.1368h7.6506l2.6171-10.6905 6.865 25.6202 3.1614-36.3492 3.9609 28.4864 1.1125-6.9395h8.7471l1.2762-7.3971 4.4477 23.966 2.3077-38.0867 1.6134 15.1554h7.5l3.3783 16.805 1.6625-13.5108h15.6946"
        opacity=".165" stroke-width=".965" stroke-linejoin="round" />
      <path class="path-B"
        d="M.8825 28.1368h7.6506l2.6171-10.6905 6.865 25.6202 3.1614-36.3492 3.9609 28.4864 1.1125-6.9395h8.7471l1.2762-7.3971 4.4477 23.966 2.3077-38.0867 1.6134 15.1554h7.5l3.3783 16.805 1.6625-13.5108h15.6946"
        stroke-width="1.765" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </g>
  </svg>
  <div>Path format set to Relative</div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="278.7779" height="172.781" viewBox="0 0 73.76 45.715">
    <g stroke-linecap="round" stroke="#00aad4" fill="none">
      <path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".965" opacity=".165"
        d="M.8825 28.1368h7.6506l2.6171-10.6905 6.865 25.6202 3.1614-36.3492 3.9609 28.4864 1.1125-6.9395h8.7471l1.2762-7.3971 4.4477 23.966 2.3077-38.0867 1.6134 15.1554h7.5l3.3783 16.805 1.6625-13.5108h15.6946" />
      <path class="path-C" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.765"
        d="m 0.8825,28.1368 h 7.6506 l 2.6171,-10.6905 6.865,25.6202 3.1614,-36.3492 3.9609,28.4864 1.1125,-6.9395 h 8.7471 l 1.2762,-7.3971 4.4477,23.966 2.3077,-38.0867 1.6134,15.1554 h 7.5 l 3.3783,16.805 1.6625,-13.5108 h 15.6946" />
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Screenshot on Safari

[image]

What I have tried.

1. Setting `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` with pixels instead of number.

Tested on IOS 12.4.7 and Safari 13.1.1

Comment: You may want to upload a picture with the rendering in Safari for those who cannot replicate the issue. I see that you have set `stroke-linecap="round"`. That might be the cause.

Comment: The one that correctly hides the stroke also has `stroke-linecap="round"`, so that isn't the issue. I edited the question to include a screenshot the rendering on Safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue has to do with Safari and Edge(Legacy) rendering decimal values on `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` when they're set from it's `getTotalLength()` method.

The fix for Safari is rounding up the value using Math.ceil.

However for Edge(Legacy) the issue still persists where the remainder of the stroke is placed at the left of the path

[image]

The solution for Edge is setting the stroke-width to zero on initialization, then when the stroke length value changes, such as an animation, change the stroke-width back to it's default value, [demo example](https://aquaductape.github.io/duo-paths-match/index.html)

```js
    const pathA = document.querySelector(".path-A");
    const pathB = document.querySelector(".path-B");
    const pathC = document.querySelector(".path-C");
    let pathAStrokeWidth = 0
    let pathBStrokeWidth = 0
    let pathCStrokeWidth = 0

    pathA.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", Math.ceil(pathA.getTotalLength()));
    pathA.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", Math.ceil(pathA.getTotalLength()));
    pathAStrokeWidth = pathA.getAttribute('stroke-width') 
    pathA.setAttribute("stroke-width", 0);

    pathB.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", Math.ceil(pathB.getTotalLength()));
    pathB.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", Math.ceil(pathB.getTotalLength()));
    pathBStrokeWidth = pathA.getAttribute('stroke-width')
    pathB.setAttribute("stroke-width", 0);

    pathC.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", Math.ceil(pathC.getTotalLength()));
    pathC.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", Math.ceil(pathC.getTotalLength()));
    pathCStrokeWidth = pathA.getAttribute('stroke-width')
    pathC.setAttribute("stroke-width", 0);
```

```css
svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>Path format set to Relative. <br/> Also has translate property accidently left over from Inkscape Program</div>
  <div>The only one that correctly hides in Safari</div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="278.7779" height="172.781" viewBox="0 0 73.76 45.715">
    <g fill="none" stroke="#00aad4" stroke-linecap="round">
      <path
        d="m 28.160858,82.187983 h 7.650572 l 2.617177,-10.690495 6.864897,25.620138 3.161464,-36.349135 3.960852,28.486407 1.112568,-6.93955 h 8.747067 l 1.276252,-7.39712 4.447672,23.966019 2.307643,-38.08671 1.613403,15.155399 h 7.50004 l 3.378248,16.804952 1.66252,-13.510699 h 15.694617"
        opacity=".165" stroke-width=".965" stroke-linejoin="round" transform="translate(-27.2784 -54.0512)" />
      <path class="path-A"
        d="m 28.160858,82.187983 h 7.650572 l 2.617177,-10.690495 6.864897,25.620139 3.161464,-36.349136 3.960852,28.486407 1.112568,-6.93955 h 8.747067 l 1.276252,-7.39712 4.447672,23.966019 2.307643,-38.08671 1.613403,15.155399 h 7.50004 l 3.378248,16.804952 1.66252,-13.510699 h 15.694617"
        stroke-width="1.765" stroke-linejoin="round" transform="translate(-27.2784 -54.0512)" />
    </g>
  </svg>
  <div>Path format set to Absolute</div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 73.76 45.715" height="172.781" width="278.7779">
    <g fill="none" stroke="#00aad4" stroke-linecap="round">
      <path
        d="M.8825 28.1368h7.6506l2.6171-10.6905 6.865 25.6202 3.1614-36.3492 3.9609 28.4864 1.1125-6.9395h8.7471l1.2762-7.3971 4.4477 23.966 2.3077-38.0867 1.6134 15.1554h7.5l3.3783 16.805 1.6625-13.5108h15.6946"
        opacity=".165" stroke-width=".965" stroke-linejoin="round" />
      <path class="path-B"
        d="M.8825 28.1368h7.6506l2.6171-10.6905 6.865 25.6202 3.1614-36.3492 3.9609 28.4864 1.1125-6.9395h8.7471l1.2762-7.3971 4.4477 23.966 2.3077-38.0867 1.6134 15.1554h7.5l3.3783 16.805 1.6625-13.5108h15.6946"
        stroke-width="1.765" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </g>
  </svg>
  <div>Path format set to Relative</div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="278.7779" height="172.781" viewBox="0 0 73.76 45.715">
    <g stroke-linecap="round" stroke="#00aad4" fill="none">
      <path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".965" opacity=".165"
        d="M.8825 28.1368h7.6506l2.6171-10.6905 6.865 25.6202 3.1614-36.3492 3.9609 28.4864 1.1125-6.9395h8.7471l1.2762-7.3971 4.4477 23.966 2.3077-38.0867 1.6134 15.1554h7.5l3.3783 16.805 1.6625-13.5108h15.6946" />
      <path class="path-C" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.765"
        d="m 0.8825,28.1368 h 7.6506 l 2.6171,-10.6905 6.865,25.6202 3.1614,-36.3492 3.9609,28.4864 1.1125,-6.9395 h 8.7471 l 1.2762,-7.3971 4.4477,23.966 2.3077,-38.0867 1.6134,15.1554 h 7.5 l 3.3783,16.805 1.6625,-13.5108 h 15.6946" />
    </g>
  </svg>
```